# Robinhood Request for Account Information Using Python Requests Module

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to use the Python "requests" module to extract account information from the Robinhood API.

```
def account_info():
    header = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    data = {"Authorization": "myactualtoken"}

    url = "https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/"
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    print r.text
account_info()
```

This is supposed to work in Curl:

```
curl -v https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/ \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Authorization: Token a9a7007f890c790a30a0e0f0a7a07a0242354114" #Token Not Real
```

When I try the Python code I get:

```
"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, REMOVE the token from the curl code!!!

Comment: It's not a real token.

Comment: Oh! Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely it is much easier to figure it out. `-H` in curl adds a header, so from your curl command (which I assume is working), I can see that `Authorization: Token a9a...` is being set as a **header**, but in your python code, you're setting it as the **POST data**.

So your solution is to simply set it as a header and remove the POST data part.

```
header = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Token a9a..."
}
```

Rest of the part is fine.

**Update**: You are entirely doing it wrong. I hadn't checked the API docs before, but after having a look at it, I now see that you were entirely doing it wrong. The supported method is **GET**, while you were making a POST query, exactly the opposite. Plus the GET url has been made specific, the URL has a unique `account_id` and ends with `positions/` endpoint.

So your code would pretty much look like this:

```
def account_info(): 
    header = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "a9a..."
        }
    url = "https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/{account_id}/positions/" 
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header) 
    print r.text 
account_info()
```

Comment: Not knowing Curl, I thought that's what it meant, and tried it already with the same result.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I don't know Curl and I am not even sure Curl works on Windows. It came from here: https://github.com/sanko/Robinhood/blob/master/Account.md#gather-account-positions.

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. You were entirely doing it wrong.

Comment: I just got it working. Everything in your code works except you have to do : "Authorization": "Bearer " + "a9a..."